# How do you store the results of a quantmod loop if the output is a single number?

Tags: r, quantmod

Please note: I'm an R novice(which is probably clear from the question).

I'm trying to turn some code which outputs the number of overnight returns above .05, into a loop which can take multiple tickers. Frustratingly, despite my best efforts, I'm apparently not having success binding the results together, perhaps because the rbind and cbind which I'm used to using don't work on single values, even if it's in a DF. What I want to end up with is a single number, (or a DF of values I can add up), which shows the number of overnight return values>.05 for all the input tickers(stored in column 1 of TEST.xlsx). Thank you so much for your help, I appreciate it!

Original(working) code:

```
library(quantmod)
data1 <- getSymbols(Symbols = "AAPL", src = "yahoo", from = Sys.Date() - 525, auto.assign = FALSE)
de = head(data1,365)
colnames(de) <- c("open","high","low","close","volume","adj.")
overnightRtn <- as.data.frame(as.numeric(de[2:nrow(de),"open"])/as.numeric(de[1:(nrow(de)-1),"close"])) - 1
r = overnightRtn[overnightRtn>.05, ]
results = NROW(r)
View(results)
```

Loop attempt:

```
library(gdata)
d = read.xls("~/Documents/TEST.xlsx", sheet = 1, stringsAsFactors=F)

library(quantmod)
sym <- as.character(d[,1])
results <- NULL

for (i in sym){
  data1 <- try(getSymbols(Symbols = i, src = "yahoo", from = Sys.Date() - 525, auto.assign = FALSE))
  if(inherits(data1, "try-error")) next
  de = head(data1,365)
  colnames(de) <- c("open","high","low","close","volume","adj.")
  overnightRtn <- as.data.frame(as.numeric(de[2:nrow(de),"open"])/as.numeric(de[1:(nrow(de)-1),"close"])) - 1
  r = as.data.frame(overnightRtn[overnightRtn>.05, ])
  x = NROW(r)
  results= rbind(x)
}

colnames(results) = c("overnightRtn")
rownames(results) = sym
View(results)
```

Error message:

```
Error in `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("AAPL", "W")) : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
```

DF of `View(results)` is 7, the (correct) value of the first ticker in my excel file of tickers - by which I mean the # of values >.05

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag` to select the previous value in a column, and `sum(overnightRtn > 0.05)` to check how many values are greater than 0.05. Here is the full code

```
library(quantmod)

sym <- c('AAPL', 'GOOG', 'MSFT')
results <- NULL

for (i in sym){
  data1 <- try(getSymbols(Symbols = i, src = 'yahoo', from = Sys.Date() - 525, auto.assign = FALSE))
  if(inherits(data1, 'try-error')) next
  de <- head(data1, 365)
  colnames(de) <- c('open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume', 'adj.')
  overnightRtn <- as.vector(de$open/lag(de$close, default = 0) - 1)
  results <- rbind(results, c(i, sum(overnightRtn > 0.05)))
}

results
#     [,1]   [,2]
#[1,] "AAPL" "3" 
#[2,] "GOOG" "4" 
#[3,] "MSFT" "3"
```

Comment: using the OHLC transformations from quantmod package and the `Delt` function overnight returns can be written in a very compact form like : `Delt(Cl(AAPL),Op(AAPL),k=1)` (here assuming symbol was created by `getSymbols`)

Comment: Thank you! How would I add more filters  to results? I tried `results <- rbind(results, c(i, sum(overnightRtn < (-0.025)), sum(overnightRtn < (-0.05)), sum(overnightRtn < (-0.075)),` which didn't work.

Comment: @RyGuy, I just tried what you suggested and it gave NA, but I was able to fix it by including `na.rm = TRUE` in the sum function. Is that the problem you were facing?

Comment: `overnightRtn` is replaced each time the loop executes. The values you see when you check `overnightRtn` are from the last iteration of the loop, i.e., for MSFT.

Comment: Yes, of course! I realized that after I posted, which is why I took it down. Thank you again, I appreciate the help.